# Render HTML retrieved from database Spring Boot, Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, tinymce

I have a Spring Boot application where I am saving content in HTML format using TinyMCE. The "content" save correctly in the database...

[HTML for saving content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6VBa.png)

[Content saved in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CZlN.png)

I'm then using Thymeleaf to display the data with the intention of keeping the styling generated in TinyMCE. I can get the "Title" and "Details" fields to display but the "content" field just displays exactly how it is stored in the database, I would like this to render as HTML

[Displaying the content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYNff.png)

```
<div class="col-sm">
    <h3>[[${document.name}]]</h3>
    <p>[[${document.details}]]</p>
    [[${document.content}]] <!--issue here-->
</div>
```

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

replacing `[[${document.content}]]` with `[(${document.content})]` resolved this issue